# "ab-initio" vs "ab initio" when we cannot use Italic font?

Tags: discussion, culture, conventions

For titles, the Stack Exchange network does not allow us to use Italic font, without resorting to the use of MathJax, which we've agreed not to use in titles, in these discussions:

- [MathJax or Unicode in titles? Does it matter? (pun intended)](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/189/5)
- [MathJax in titles: Can we give users a warning prompt (or an error prompt) when they try this?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340/5)

*ab initio* is a Latin phrase, and the most common convention is to Italicize Latin phrases. A convention I've seen is "[If italicizing, then no hyphen. If not italicizing, then hyphenate.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/325674/21450)". In the same discussion, another person said "[the phrase should be either italicized or hyphenated, but not both](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/537615/21450)".

For these reasons, (at least) the following question titles have had hyphens in them:

- [Difference between Van der Waals (DFT-D and DFT-D3) corrections in ab-initio calculations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/revisions/1119/1)
- [Rotational magnetic moment and ab-initio calculations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3614/5)
- [Do bonds between the atoms influence ab-initio energies?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9515/5)
- [Floquet's Theorem and ab-initio Calculations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3615/5)
- [How to find the Cauchy stress tensor in solids using ab-initio methods?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8420/5)
- [Are nuclear ab-initio methods related to materials ab-initio methods?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/4177/5), and most recently:
- [Ab-initio molecular dynamics of liquid systems: best tools and resources](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10086/5)

When searching ab-initio (without quotes) on Google, the first page of results includes [this one](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095344143;jsessionid=FD0834273F0B8A98D856342922A39A11) which uses the hyphen and seems to come from [this reference](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/acref/9780199204632.001.0001/acref-9780199204632-e-3) which was published by Oxford University Press.

It has also been argued by one of our users that:

> "[The hyphen is just plain wrong. Always.](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10086/ab-initio-molecular-dynamics-of-liquid-systems-best-tools-and-resources?noredirect=1#comment21387_10086)"

I think this is also a fair perspective, as the procedure for what to do in this situation has not been codified in any laws or authoritative rule books as far as I know. The situation in which the platform **does not allow** Italicization is probably extremely rare (with the Stack Exchange network possibly being a unique case). I'm sure a lot of dictionaries advise people to Italicize Latin phrases, but they don't tell us what to do when Italicization is made impossible.

Shall we:

- **use** a hyphen when the phrase *ab initio* appears in a title?
- **not use** a hyphen in this situation?
- allow both conventions, depending on what the OP uses in the original post?

Comment: In Portuguese, we put any word in other language in Italic font. How it is in English?

Comment: In English we tend to put Latin words in Italic font, but SE doesn't let us do it in titles :'(